# Show ads based on viewport width

Tags: jquery, viewport, web-deployment-project

I am working on a responsive design and would like to display a different ad only when the viewport width is less or equal to 480px.

I guess this can be done in jquery. Someone please help

Thanks

Comment: No code, no chocolate... Please provide what you have done.

Comment: Btw, ($('#id').width() < 480)?$('#id').html(ads1):$('#id').html(ads2);

Comment: I'm stuck here. <script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){

    if (jQuery(window).width() <= 480
       ) {
        document.write("Hello World!");
    }
});
</script> How do I run ad the script?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Relevant quote from the link:

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features. Among the media features that can be used in media queries are ‘width’, ‘height’, and ‘color’. By using media queries, presentations can be tailored to a specific range of output devices without changing the content itself.

[See browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)